# Tracking the user's location while in background in iOS

Tags: ios, background, location, core-location, cllocationmanager

I've read Apple's documentation regarding this, but there are some things that I don't find clear:

1) To get location events in background, is it necessary to call to `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` method, as in code snippet in [iOS App Programming Guide - Executing a Finite-Length Task in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW28)? It is only needed if you use the standard location service, or also when using the significant-change service?

2) Does the significant-change location service require to enable the background mode?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` gives you a maximum of 3 minutes (iOS 7) to complete something in the background.  This isn't really a background task, it just sets a flag (in effect) that says if the app gets backgrounded, let the main thread keep executing for a few minutes so it can finish something.

Comment: Thanks, so... will my code in `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` keep running as if the app were active without need of doing anything else? Just enabling the background mode for locations?

Comment: What I need to do in background is to store, send and display some notifications according to the user's position. I need the standard location service. And I need to support iOS5+

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of questions, you should search the questions on stack overflow that are tagged with core-location, [like these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bcore-location%5d%20background)